# React bootstrap css take over other components style and changes size

Tags: css, reactjs, styles, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I have a problem, React Bootstrap's (react-bootstrap.github.io) CSS took over my other components's style and made their buttons, fonts, inputs and etc bigger.

Is there is anyway to prevent or avoid that but to use the Modal CSS?
See screenshots below.

**Modal.jsx** // The "problematic" code

```
 import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
 import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'; 

     <link 
        rel='stylesheet'
       href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
     integrity='sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We'
       crossorigin='anonymous'
    />;
```

With the 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
[image: With bootstrap css]

 
Without bootstrap CSS
[image: Without bootstrap css]

Comment: Use `!important` for your styles. for instance: `width: "10px" !important`

Comment: @MajidM. My styles are in a CSS files, thats a lot of work, is there a shorter way to do that?